# How to deploy Ingress to expose MinIO cluster outside

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minio, kubernetes-service, k3s

I have setup MinIO in kubernetes (k3s) - one node implementation.

**Services**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio
  namespace: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: minio
  ports:
  - port: 9011
    name: minio
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-service
  namespace: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: minio
  ports:
  - port: 9012
    targetPort: 9011
    protocol: TCP
```

**Sateful Set**

```
      [. . .]
      containers:
      - name: ches
        image: minio/minio
        args:
        - server
        - /data
        [. . .]
        - containerPort: 9000
          hostPort: 9011
        [. . .]
```

Command `kubectl logs minio-0 -n minio` returns the following:

- API: http://10.42.0.14:9000 http://127.0.0.1:9000
- Console: http://10.42.0.14:41989 http://127.0.0.1:41989

I am trying to setup Ingress. The steps that followed are:

**Setup an Ingress Controller**

From here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

**Create an Internal Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-service-ingress
  namespace: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  selector:
    app: minio
  ports:
  - port: 9011
    name: minio
```

**Create Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minio-ingress
  namespace: minio
spec:
  rules:
  - host: minio.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: minio-service-ingress
            port:
              number: 9011
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

When executing `kubectl get ing -n minio`:

```
NAME            CLASS    HOSTS           ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
minio-ingress   <none>   minio.com       192.168.1.14   80      43m
```

In /etc/hosts I added the entry:

> 192.168.1.14    minio.com

However, when I am trying to enter `http://minio.com/` in browser I get:

> Bad Gateway

Am I missing something here?